# Error 500 - Internal Server Error with Curl file upload

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, curl

I am trying to upload remote file with Curl but it says 500 internal error

Here's my code

```
<?php
$shahab="file.jpg";
$ch = curl_init("https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/file.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
array('zip'=>"@$shahab"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print "$result";
?>
```

Can anyone help me what's wrong?

Comment: What returns the 500? Your PHP code, or the remote server? It isn't clear. If it's your PHP which returns that, then you need to check your PHP error log file. 500 is just a generic error message which (deliberately, for security reasons) doesn't reveal any details about the underlying problem. Go and get the real error message, and then you stand a chance of understanding the specific problem and fixing it.

Comment: (But if the 500 error is the response to the cURL request, you need to contact the owner of the remote server to ask what went wrong, or whether you did something wrong in the request you made. Or read their API documentation, if they have any.)

Comment: if I use http then it says 301 moved permanently if I use https then it says 500 internal server error.. I have contacted to my hosting they said there's issue in script I need to consult with expert.

Comment: Again, what returns the 500? **Your** PHP code as shown above, or the URL you're making the cURL request to? You didn't clarify this point.

Comment: `I have contacted to my hosting they said there's issue in script`...well their technical support will not debug the specifics of your code for you. Like I said, look in your PHP error log file on your server, if it's your PHP code which is faulting.

Comment: I get this error please see this screenshot https://prnt.sc/zrzodf

Comment: Ok. So, as I mentioned twice already, you need to check your PHP error_log file on your server, to get the underlying error message.

Comment: I checked in error_log it says this ----> public_html/wp-content/plugins" is writeable by others

Comment: That seems more like a warning than an exception. Are you sure that's all there is? Does it say any more than that?

Comment: Yes all are there.. I am running script on this path mywebsite.com/adil/test.php

Comment: then uploaded path will be this one mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228821/discussion-between-adil-ali-and-adyson).